# Unable to clone Private Git Repo in VS Code Remote Container

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have a VM running RedHat 8.6, which is running multiple LXC containers, each with Ubuntu 22.04 installed.

The RedHat VM is used as a SSH proxy to get to the LXC Containers. There are approx 10 developers in my team, each developer has their own LXC Container.

An example VS Code SSH Configuration is as follows

```
IdentityFile c:\users\simon.carr2\.ssh\id_ed25519
Host jump-box
  HostName 10.15.236.74
  IdentityFile c:\users\simon.carr2\.ssh\id_ed25519
  User bob

Host container
  HostName 10.36.165.29
  User bob
  IdentityFile c:\users\simon.carr2\.ssh\id_ed25519
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p jump-box
```

I can connect to the Host called container (which is proxied through jump-box)

Once connected, in VSCode, I try to `Clone Repository in Container Volume`
When prompted I put the https link to my on-prem private repo (Running in GitLab)

But I am given the following error in the terminal

```
[85754 ms] Dev Containers 0.266.1 in VS Code 1.74.0 (5235c6bb189b60b01b1f49062f4ffa42384f8c91).
[85754 ms] Start: Run: ssh container /bin/sh
[85784 ms] Start: Run in host: id -un
[87248 ms] bob
[87249 ms] 
[87251 ms] Start: Run in host: cat /etc/passwd
[87310 ms] Start: Run in host: echo ~
[87421 ms] /home/bob
[87422 ms] 
[87424 ms] Start: Run in host: test -x '/home/bob/.vscode-remote-containers/bin/5235c6bb189b60b01b1f49062f4ffa42384f8c91/node'
[87546 ms] 
[87547 ms] 
[87547 ms] Exit code 1
[87548 ms] Start: Run in host: test -x '/home/bob/.vscode-server/bin/5235c6bb189b60b01b1f49062f4ffa42384f8c91/node'
[87654 ms] 
[87655 ms] 
[87656 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/home/bob/.vscode-server/bin/5235c6bb189b60b01b1f49062f4ffa42384f8c91/node_modules/node-pty/package.json'
[87761 ms] 
[87761 ms] 
[87761 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/home/bob/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/vscode-remote-containers-server-0.266.1.js'
[87865 ms] 
[87866 ms] 
[87898 ms] userEnvProbe: loginInteractiveShell (default)
[87899 ms] userEnvProbe shell: /bin/bash
[88078 ms] userEnvProbe PATHs:
Probe:     '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
Container: None
[88188 ms] Start: Run in Host: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[88422 ms] 1.41
[101518 ms] Start: Run in Host: git ls-remote https://gitlab.mydomain.net/gitlab-instance-eb474769/syclops-gui.git
[101724 ms] 
[101725 ms] fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.mydomain.net': No such device or address

[101725 ms] Exit code 128
```

How do I get VSCode to prompt me for Git Credentials?